# How to connect from Docker container to the host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu

My problem is that im trying to connect to a Docker host(Im running on Ubuntu) from a container. Ive tried several solutions including adding extra_hosts: host.docker.internal:host-gateway, but still im not able to establish the connection. Im running docker with docker-compose up.

So for example when i run script the `requests.get("http//:host.docker.internal:8000")` in the container then receive an error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f18ac13dd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

.

This is my docker-compose.yml

````
 version: 3.7

services:
  web:
    container_name: schedule_model_service-api
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    command: startserver
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"


  worker:
    container_name: schedule_model_service-worker
    build: .
    command: celeryworker
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - web
      - postgres
      - redis

  redis:
    container_name: schedule_model_service-redis
    image: redis:6.2.6
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/redis:/var/lib/redis
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: on-failure

  postgres:
    container_name: schedule_model_service-db
    image: postgres:14.1
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: on-failure```
````

Comment: I want to add that this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach solution did not work for me.

Comment: I think your docker-compose is wrong. host.internal work very well. Compare it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136530/how-to-connect-api-with-web-spa-through-docker/63207679#63207679

Comment: Well, whatever else is wrong, this `requests.get("http//:host.docker.internal:8000")`  is going to fail until the extra `:` after `http://` is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the container needs to connect to a host or a remote service, you need his ip or domain. **Any other workaround only will work on your laptop or is just for academic purposes**, not valid in the real scenarios with real users. For example: a container in aws needs to connect to an azure mysql.

In your case, you need the local ip. As I explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52213178/3957754 you could get the ip before the `docker-compose up`:

```
export MACHINE_HOST_IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
docker-compose up ...
```

And in your compose file use this value. For example of you have a mysql on your host and your container need it, you could use:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  wordpress:
    environment:
      DB_HOST : ${MACHINE_HOST_IP}:3306
      DB_USER : usr_wordpress
```

Review:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173352/what-is-the-difference-between-publishing-808080-and-80808080-in-a-docker-run/52213178#52213178
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136530/how-to-connect-api-with-web-spa-through-docker/63207679#63207679

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've got an extra colon in `requests.get("http//:host.docker.internal:8000")`. It should be `requests.get("http//host.docker.internal:8000")`.

You might have hit a bug in requests' URL parsing; from the exception message you can see it's trying to connect to `localhost:8000` when it would make more sense to complain about the malformed URL.